# Regex to split path value C:\Users\goudarsh\Desktop\Perl_test_scripts\rtl2gds

Tags: regex

I need the perl regex to split the following value

```
  $path = 'C:\Users\goudarsh\Desktop\Perl_test_scripts\sample';
```

i tried following code seems not working

```
my @var = split(/\\/,$path);
        print @var;
        if(grep /rtl2gds/, @var){
            print $path;
        }
```

i am not getting where i am doing wrong.

even i tried following

```
 my @var = split(//\/,$path);
        print @var;
        if(grep /rtl2gds/, @var){
            print $path;
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think you need a regular expression?

Comment: @jonathon Reinhart i need to split the given path and then if the path contains a particular entry (folder name with rtl2gds) then i am interested in that folder, do let me know if you still need any clarifications

Comment: my input path will vary at every instance.

Comment: What does "seems not working" mean? What output are you seeing that makes you think that?

Comment: @MattJacob i am expecting output to be split values of my input path and if those values consist rtl2gds folder then i am interested in that path.

Comment: Just give me a regex which splits  $path value and split criteria should be by '\'

Comment: You know that `$path` doesn't contain `rtl2gds`, right?

Comment: @MattJacob I know but my input varies from time to time

Comment: When you print `@var` In your first example, what do you see?

Comment: when i print @var, I have the complete $path value printed and even i tried to print $var[1] and i got Use of uninitialized value in say at file2.pl line 22

Comment: @MattJacob: Why don't you explain what you mean? I understand your frustration, but there is a better way to resolve this exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works fine... have you actually run it?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $path = 'C:\Users\goudarsh\Desktop\Perl_test_scripts\sample';
my @var = split(/\\/, $path);
print Dumper(\@var);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'C:',
          'Users',
          'goudarsh',
          'Desktop',
          'Perl_test_scripts',
          'sample'
        ];
```

Comment: I am sorry i am not lying! may be i was to quick for not observing closely! it works fine now thanks alot

Answer (score 5):

Instead of relying on manual splitting, I recommend using [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html)

```
use File::Spec;

my ($volume, $dir, $file) = File::Spec->splitpath($path);
my @components = File::Spec->splitdir($dir);
push @components, $file;
```

Now `@components` is your desired array with a safer and more portable implementation.

Comment: Path::Class is far more friendly than File::Spec

Comment: @ikegami File::Spec is a core module though.

Comment: @all thanks for letting me know various methods of doing one thing!

Comment: @ikegami: Forgive me for my late reply: I have been travelling. Aside from my disagreement that `Path::Class` is superior to `File::Spec` you are still missing my point, which is that *of the methods in core that allow you to access the components of a file path*, it is irrelevant that there are poorer ways to achieve the same thing. I doubt if you were recommending that `Path::Class` be installed just for this purpose, and likewise [TLP was](http://bit.ly/1OCKnV1) not detracting from `Path::Class`. You were both simply citing each module's advantages

Comment: @ikegami: *"you learn best by finding your own mistakes"* is the antithesis of Stack Overflow, which is intended as a resource to help people recover from their mistakes. You have a habit of writing enigmatic comments that only half explain your meaning, and it seems peculiar and inaapropriate here

Comment: @Borodin, Re "it is irrelevant that there are poorer ways to achieve the same thing", I never said otherwise.

Comment: @Borodin, Re "You were both simply citing each module's advantages", No, I said being in core is not an advantage on its own. I think those were my exact words, in fact.

Comment: @Borodin, Re "'you learn best by finding your own mistakes' is the antithesis of Stack Overflow," 100% false. SO is about about teaching, not just giving the answer.

Comment: I was asked what a Path::Class solution would look like (by sidyll?). `my @components = file("C:...")->components`

Comment: @ikegami not by me but I remember seeing that comment too. And thanks a for showing it, nice module to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Path::File` docs are a bit convoluted, here is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;

use Path::Class;  # Exports file() by default

my $path = file('/Users/7stud/perl_programs/myprog.pl');

say $path->basename;   # => myprog.pl 
say $path->dir;        # => /Users/7stud/perl_programs
say $path->volume;     # => ""

my @components = $path->components;  

for my $component (@components) {
    say "-->$component<--";
}

--output:--
--><--
-->Users<--
-->7stud<--
-->perl_programs<--
-->myprog.pl<--
```

On Windows, a module will load automatically that understands Window's style paths. To examine a Window's style path on a Unix system:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;

use Path::Class qw{ foreign_file };

my $path = foreign_file('Win32', 'C:\Users\goudarsh\Desktop\Perl_test_scripts\sample');

say $path->basename;   # => sample 

say $path->dir;        # => C:\Users\goudarsh\Desktop\Perl_test_scripts
say $path->volume;     # => C:

my @components = $path->components;

for my $component (@components) {
    say "-->$component<--";
}

--output:--
--><--
-->Users<--
-->goudarsh<--
-->Desktop<--
-->Perl_test_scripts<--
-->sample<--
```